# wget from file and save as acording to file name

Tags: wget, url

I have multiple files, each file contains a URL.

How can I use `wget` to read each file and download the URL inside it, save it as the container file name?

EX : file `name.frm` contains :

```
http://some_domain.com/459830945.txt
```

I need the URL to be saved as : 
file `name.txt`

Comment: All files have the `frm` extension and are located in the same directory?

Comment: Each remote file is a single line of text containing only a URL?  You want to read each remote file and save that single line URL as a local file with a specified name?  This doesn't sound like something you would use wget for but rather curl unless I'm missing something about what you're trying to do.

Comment: i have about 1000 local files , ech file contains 1 url in it , i want wget to read each file , and save the output as the file name

Comment: all the frm files is in the same directory

Comment: what i think i need is something like this : 
for each file : set file name as string  $filename
then grep content | wget -i $URL -o $filename

but i am new with linux i need some help with it please !

Answer (score 1):

Since `wget` has a `-i` option to read one or more URLs from a file, a simple shell loop should suffice:

```
for f in *.frm; do 
  wget -i "$f" -O "${f%.frm}.txt"
done
```

If you can't use the `-i` option, then you can read a single line from each file using the bash built-in `read` function:

```
for f in *.frm; do 
  IFS= read -r url < "$f" && wget "$url" -O "${f%.frm}.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thank you
i tried this , it can not read the content of the files , its only read the file name !

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script in the same directory with the next content.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
files=$(ls -1 *.frm)
for file in ${files[@]}; do
  downloaded_file=$(echo $file | sed 's/\.frm/.txt/')
  url_file=$(more $file)
  wget $url_file -O $downloaded_file
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Now, execute the bash file.

```
bash script.sh
```

There is no solution using only `wget` and you need to mix `sed` (any utility to text processing) and read the url because file with urls in wget don't have custom name of the file.

[My gist](https://gist.github.com/cosmoscalibur/16e77e0995f4416fc09b7944ac53e064).

Comment: thank you ! i will try iy now !

Comment: thank you , 
when i apply this command for folder with 1 .frm file it work , but when there is more than 1 file , it return with : 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Comment: FYI this answer falls into [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Also `sed 's/.frm/.txt/'` will replace the *first* occurrence of any single character followed by `frm` - so a filename `afrm.frm` would become `.txt.frm` instead of `afrm.txt`. There's really no need to use sed at all, but if you do, at least anchor it and make the `.` literal ex. `sed 's/\.frm$/.txt/'`

Comment: But "401 Unauthorized" is about authentication problem. URL is not public resource? @AlaaAl-ashari .

Comment: Yes, you are right @steeldriver , I have the mistake using dot. In the case of Bash pitfall, my workaround is change the IFS character.